# sudo apt-get update -> Failed to start apt-news.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out

Tags: 23.04

Firefox and chroming are not starting with error "Bus error (core dumped)". So, I run apt-get update and get an error. I think the cause is org.freedesktop.systemd1, but I could not get any further.
I tried everything I could find so far, no change.

```
sudo apt-get update 
Failed to start apt-news.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
See system logs and 'systemctl status apt-news.service' for details.
Failed to start esm-cache.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
See system logs and 'systemctl status esm-cache.service' for details.
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                                     
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                             
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [109 kB]
Fetched 109 kB in 24s (4,467 B/s)                                                                                         
Error: Timeout was reached
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Please add (as in the message noted) the output of `systemctl status apt-news.service` and `systemctl status esm-cache.service` to the question.